# Shell script: get file path till some desired text

Tags: shell

I need a way to fetch the desired file path as mentioned below:

example:

file paths: (Desired input)

```
/root/tmp/uname/abc.txt  

/root/tmp/uname/abc/abc.txt

/root/uname/abc.txt
```

Now, I want to print path till `uname/` directory.

like: (expected output)

```
/root/tmp/uname

/root/tmp/uname

/root/uname
```

---

Need to extract path till any desired directory.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please see the [How do I ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We like to help, but we can't solve your homework.

Comment: How do you plan to take the input is it in a text file ?

Comment: you can through it in another file using > filename. #the input text is input of which command?? you can use pipe to redirect it into awk.

Comment: @VinayShukla - yes, we are taking inputs from text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable substitution `${var%pattern}` produces the value of `var` with any suffix matching `pattern` removed.

```
for p in /root/tmp/uname/abc.txt /root/tmp/uname/abc/abc.txt /root/uname/abc.txt
do
    echo "${p%/uname*}/uname"
done
```

There is also `${var#pattern}` to remove any matching prefix.

If the paths are in a file, use a `while read` instead of a `for` loop.

```
while read -r p; do
    echo "${p%/uname*}/uname"
done <file
```

... though in that case, `sed 's%\(/uname\)/.*%1%' file` will be simpler and faster.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment. It works for me; demo at http://ideone.com/fA8q8V

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the file `temp1.txt` contains

```
 root@nviewsrvr ~Competitive ] cat temp1.txt
/root/tmp/uname/abc.txt

/root/tmp/uname/abc/abc.txt

/root/uname/abc.txt
```

Following script takes the input from this file and gives you the desired result.

```
#!/bin/bash

 cat temp1.txt|while read LINE
 do
    for p in `echo ${LINE}`
    do
        echo "${p%/uname*}/uname"
    done
 done
```

Results:

```
[xvishuk@ecamolx1820 ~/Competitive]$ ./forUname.sh
/root/tmp/uname
/root/tmp/uname
/root/uname
```

I have hardcoded the file as `temp1.txt` you can pass them as arguments to the script.

Comment: That's a [Useless Use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) and a [useless `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) to top it off.

Comment: It is better than hardcoding the filename aint it ? as he has the path in a file hence suggested so

Comment: Resolving these coding anti-patterns does not require you to  hardcode the file name.

Comment: I have not hardcoded anything it is your code which has hardcoding `for p in /root/tmp/uname/abc.txt /root/tmp/uname/abc/abc.txt /root/uname/abc.txt`